# Google Apps Script search function needs to compare strings containing numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm building an incredibly simple database (really just a minor in-sheet MVC) to standardize data storage practices in order to automate some things. I'm trying to build a search function so that data entries can be edited, but I'm having trouble getting my search parameters to compare as they come in an "ABC 1234" format. I have a feeling I simply don't know the language well enough yet, but here's my search function;

```
function search() {

  const searchValue = searchCell.getValue()
  const data = dataWS.getRange("A2:I").getValues()
  data.filter(r => r[8] == searchValue)
  const recordsFound = data.filter(r => r[8] == searchValue)
  if(recordsFound.length == 0) return

  fieldRange.forEach((f,i) => formWS.getRange(f).setValue(recordsFound[0][i+1]))


}
```

The cell locations and sheet locations and everything are established globally so if there's anything missing here you need, I'll gladly provide it.

Both == and === did not work and I imagine I'm simply missing some knowledge or experience here, but I'm also having trouble tracking down what I'm missing. Tough when you don't know what you don't know. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" and it points to the if comparison line.

Comment: The code doesn't look well. There can be anything. For starters you can try to remove the line `data.filter....` (it doesn't work anyway) and add `;` at the end of each line. Since `return` without a `;` will try to return all the code from the next lines, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding so this is self taught, why does data.filter not work? I'm looking to compare cell content to a search string and print the entire corresponding row to different cells. Basically looking up an entry in a database but solely in google sheets.

Comment: If anyone comes across this looking for the solution, I ended up getting my search key values from my data in an array, then .indexOf(searchValue)+1 returns it's position in the array plus 1 since arrays start at 0 and rows start at 1. If the result is 0 that means it wasn't found (indexOf() returns -1 when not found) and otherwise it returned the row I wanted to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finding Search Value

```
function search() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const searchValue = sh.getRange("?").getValue();
  const dataWS= ss.getSheetByName("?")
  const data = dataWS.getRange("A2:I" + dataWS.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[8] == searchValue);//r[8] is column 9
  //I don't know where you're going from here so I'll just logger.log the data
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Using textfinder is also pretty easy

#### Using textfinder

```
function search() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const searchValue = sh.getRange("?").getValue();
  const dataWS= ss.getSheetByName("?")
  const data = dataWS.getRange("A2:I" + dataWS.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(searchValue).findAll().map(r => dataWS.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,dataWS.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have the search function find a row with the searchValue in it and then put the values in the row into an array for a model view control style edit entry. I follow everything you're doing in this code until the last line where you log it. 

I get that A2:I is the range we're looking at but if I'm trying to match a search string to a cell content why would I use .getLastRow()? Not arguing, just trying to understand. Did I not explain the intent well?

Comment: I just did a bit of research on textfinder and I think that it could work perfectly for what I'm trying to accomplish, going to look into having the textfinder functions spit back the range I need to edit. Thank you I think this has steered me in the right direction! Sorry if my lack of knowledge is showing too starkly, I'm learning. I appreciate the input.